# main.cpp:65:16: error: expected primary-expression before '*' token

Tags: c++

hi guys i have written a code related binary search trees and if you look at the line of my code in "findnode" function which is

```
node<tree<int>*> obj;
```

and when i compile my code it says

```
main.cpp:65:2: error: 'node' was not declared in this scope 
main.cpp:65:16: error: expected primary-expression before '*' token
main.cpp:65:17: error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
main.cpp:65:19: error: 'obj' was not declared in this scope
```

All of these errors are related to the line I have mentioned above. So how can I fix this?

My code:

```
#include<iostream>
#define null NULL
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class tree {
private:
    T val;
    tree<T>*  left;
    tree<T>* right;

public:
    tree()
    {
        left = null;
        right = null;
    }
    tree<T>* addnode(tree<int>* root, T info);
    void printinorder(tree<int>*);
    void findnode(tree<int>* root);
    void findlevel(tree<int>* enter, int num);

};
template<typename T>
tree<T>* tree<T>::addnode(tree<int>* root, T info)
{
    if (root == null)
    {
        tree* root = new tree;
        root->val = info;
        return root;
    }
    else if (root->val > info)
    {
        root->left = addnode(root->left, info);
    }
    else if (root->val < info)
    {
        root->right = addnode(root->right, info);
    }
    else
        cout << info << " is already exists in tree." << endl;
    return root;
}
template<typename T>
void tree<T>::printinorder(tree<int>* root)
{
    if (root != null)
    {
        if (root->left != null)
        {
            printinorder(root->left);
        }
        cout << root->val << " ";
        if (root->right != null)
        {
            printinorder(root->right);
        }

    }
}
template<typename T>
void tree<T>::findnode(tree<int>* root)
{
    node<tree<int>*> obj;
    tree<int>* help;
    help = root;
    obj.push(help);
    while (!obj.isEmpty())
    {
        help = obj.pop();
        findlevel(root, help->val);
        if (help->left != null)
        {
            obj.push(help->left);
        }
        if (help->right != null)
        {
            obj.push(help->right);
        }
    }
}
template<typename T>
void tree<T>::findlevel(tree<int>* enter, int num)
{
    static int count;
    if (enter == null)
    {
        cout << enter->val << " is not in your tree" << endl;
    }
    else if (enter->val == num)
    {
        cout << num << "----->>>>level :" << count << endl;
        count = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        count++;
        if (enter->val > num)
        {
            findlevel(enter->left, num);
        }
        else
        {
            findlevel(enter->right, num);
        }
    }
}

template<typename T>
class node {
private:
    T data;
    node* next;
    node* top;
    node* head;
    node* back;
public:
    node()
    {
        head = null;
        top = null;
        next = null;
        back = null;
    }
    void push(T info1)
    {
        if (head == null)
        {
            node* n = new node;
            n->data = info1;
            head = n;
            top = n;
        }
        else
        {
            node* n = new node;
            n->data = info1;
            n->next = top;
            top = n;
        }

    }
    T pop()
    {
        T d;
        d = head->data;
        if (top != head)
        {
            back = top;
            while (back->next != head)
            {
                back = back->next;
            }
            head = back;
            return d;
        }
        else
        {
            head = null;
            return d;
        }

        return d;

    }
    bool isEmpty()
    {
        return head == null;
    }
};
int main()
{
    tree<int>* shoh = null;
    char ch;
    int i;
    while (true)
    {
        cin >> ch;
        switch (ch)
        {
        case 'i': cin >> i;
            shoh = shoh->addnode(shoh, i);
            break;
        case 'p': shoh->printinorder(shoh);
            break;
        case 't':
            shoh->findnode(shoh);
            break;
        case 'e': exit(0);
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In c++ you should use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`. There is certainly no need to `#define null NULL`, and I wouldn't recommend `#define null nullptr` either.

Comment: As the errors explain, `node` isn't declared where you use it, it's only defined later. You must declare anything you use *before* you use it.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Why not `#define null nullptr`?  It should be a good way to find bugs :)

Comment: actually it was for fast typing rather than writing NULL with capital letters or nullptr always. but anyway thanks. i appreciate

Answer (score 1):

You're defining the type `node` further down in the file. It's not known yet when you reference it at line 65. Consider moving that class definition up above the definition of the `tree` class.

Comment: ohh thanks man. it worked finally:) i don't know why i didn't pay attention to this kind of simple mistake. it was my bad. maybe i am so tired after exams